# Как сделать полый квадрат?

Tags: c

Не могу справится с задачей по программированию. Есть задача: написать программу, чтобы она выводила полый квадрат. Использовать только While.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int a = 0;
    printf("Please input side a");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    int count = 1;
    while (count <= a) {
        printf("*");
        count++;
    }
    printf("n");
    int count2 = 1;
    while (count2 <= (a - 2)) {
        a // ????????    
        count2++;
    }
    int count3 = 1;
    while (count <= a) {
        printf("*");
        count3++;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Я понял, как сделать, чтобы выводился полный квадрат, но вот с полым не получается, точнее не могу понять, как в начале поставить `*` и в конце `*`, а по середине пробелы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SQUARE_WIDTH 10

int main()
{
    int height = SQUARE_WIDTH, i;

    while( height )
    {
        putchar( '*' );
        i = SQUARE_WIDTH - 2;
        while( i-- )
        {
            if( height == SQUARE_WIDTH || height == 1 ) putchar( '*' );
            else putchar( ' ' );
        }   
        putchar( '*' );
        putchar( '\n' );
        height--;
    }
    return SQUARE_WIDTH;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно пример попроще дать? Я ещё много не понимаю, не хотелось дальше лезть, без базового накопления знаний. Например как у меня было описано можно так сделать? и без константы?

Comment: Описано:

>написать программу, чтобы она выводила полый квадрат. Использовать только While.

Так и сделано, как ещё проще я не знаю. Ввод стороны у вас реализован через scanf(), поэтому повторяться не стал. Ну вставьте его вместо height = SQUARE_HEIGHT, принципиально ничего не изменится :)

Comment: Ну я сделал чуть по другому без условия.. Не знаю может неправильно как то со стороны, но с моими знания я только вот так смог сделать:

 int count3 = 3;
   
   while (count3 <= a)
   {
      printf("*");
         
      int count4 = 1;
      while (count4 <= (a - 2))
      {
         printf (" ");
         count4++;
      }
         
      printf ("*\n");
      count3++;
   }

Answer (score 3):

Так? (Про while забыл)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int a = 0;
  int i = 0;
  printf ("Please input side a>");
  scanf ("%d", &a);

  while(++i <= a) {
    int j = 0;
    while (++j <= a) 
      putchar((i == 1 || j == 1 || i == a || j == a) ? '*' : ' ');
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Если номер строки или столбца равен 1 или стороне квадрата, печатать звёздочку, иначе -- пробел. После окончания строки печатать `\n`

Comment: спасибо, интересно, всё больше поражаюсь как можно делать одно и тоже очень разными способами, и все верны в принципе.